# Creating blank CSV file with headers only

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to create a CSV file for logging server reboot information.  Reboot status, last reboot timestamp and current reboot timestamp.

I've found code to create a CSV as follows but when I open the CSV in notepad, there's a blank line.  How can I create a CSV file with headers and no blank line?  I've tried looking for alternate methods for creating a blank CSV file with headers but none of them work as this does.

The blank line in notepad `"","","",""`

```
#Create CSV
$headers = "Server", "Status", "LastRebootTime", "CurrentRebootTime"
$psObject = New-Object psobject
foreach($header in $headers)
 {
  Add-Member -InputObject $psobject -MemberType noteproperty -Name $header -Value ""
 }
$psObject | Export-Csv d:\scripts\WorkFlowTest.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What do you mean by blank rows? You have 3 rows looking like `"","","",""` or? Maybe post a sample of the blank lines from the CSV

Comment: Or even better: boil your problem down to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question using MCVE.  I was trying to provide the whole script.

Comment: Not able to reproduce - sure it's not because you're appending to an existing file?

Comment: I have a suspicion my problem is created by the loops I have and I added a `Continue` statement, now my CSV log file has no blank rows.  Consider me stumped!

Comment: @user4317867 Show us the loops then. The code here is missing the problem.

Comment: Vote to close this question in favor of the [previous question I thought was answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387224/server-reboot-script-with-timed-loop)

Comment: How does $server get assigned a value?

Comment: I'm using `Param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$server)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks go out [to Invoke-Parallel](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/Invoke-Parallel/blame/master/Invoke-Parallel/Invoke-Parallel.ps1) which uses the following code, the important part being `[0]`

```
$CSV= 'd:\scripts\Test.csv'
New-Item -ItemType file -path $LogFile -force | Out-Null 
("" | Select Date, Action, Runtime, Status, Details | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType -Delimiter ";")[0] | Out-File $CSV
```

Comment: Well done, but it has to be noted, that if you then want to work with the file after the above, a simple:
$CSVFile = Import-CSV $CSV
won't do. Powershell is not going to create properties matching the header names inside a variable $CSVFile, like Powershell normally does if there's at least one line of data.
We'll need to explicitly specify what the header is:
$CSVFile = Import-CSV $CSV -Header Date, Action, Runtime, Status, Details
I thought this would save somebody time.

Answer (score 1):

By default, PowerShell uses Unicode, which apparently causes Excel to load the data into a single column. Try the following, which creates an ASCII output file:

```
# Begin "here string"

$csv = @"
index,name
1,Ed
2,Teresa
"@ # End of "here string"

$csv | Out-File temp.csv -Encoding ASCII

start temp.csv
```